# How to change the title of an event

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm using fullcalender 5 and i'm trying to make a menu that can change the title of the event selected.
the only problem is i can't find a way to change it except to remove the event and make a new one,which is not the best.
i found old ways to do it in the fullcalendar 4 version like "updatevent" but there are not working anymore.(Also they can not be found anymore on the official docs)
Any idea?
Thank you.

Comment: What you need most probably is [setProp](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Event-setProp)

Comment: `i found old ways to do it in the fullcalendar 4 version like "updatevent"`...no, that didn't exist in v4 either. You're probably thinking of v3. The v3-v4 upgrade guide available in the documentation explains very clearly what has replaced updateEvent - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/upgrading-from-v3#event-model . `they can not be found anymore on the official docs`...they can, because documentation for all previous versions is still available on the website.